# Xcode 6's Playground feature for Visual Studio or another IDE that uses C++?

Tags: c++, xcode, visual-studio, ide

I have been fascinated by how Apple introduced this playground feature to Swift and Xcode where you can see the results as you program.

Is there an addon/extension for Visual Studio, or a different IDE that does the same kind of feature for C++?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Since it is related I want to mention that there were tools to live code c++ with clang.

Answer (score 4):

I don't know about C++, but for C# you can try http://dotnetfiddle.net

The XCode playground feature doesn't let you include header files and such, and it's only for Swift, not Objective C, fyi.

I, too, would like to see the capability in VS!

Comment: Update: Xamarin Studio also has a "Sketch" feature. I haven't played with it much, but always good to have options :)

Comment: Yep, the Xamarin IDE allows live code sketching with C#, it's almost the same as Swift playground.